# Convert List into string single quoted elements in brackets - Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a list

```
["user2","user","user4"]
```

I want to convert into a string like this:

```
  2> "('user2','user','user4')".
"('user2','user','user4')"
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using list comprehension to add the single quotes to the start and end, and then `string:join/2` to join them with a comma separator:

```
1> ["'" ++ X ++ "'" || X <- ["user2","user","user4"]].
["'user2'","'user'","'user4'"]
2> string:join(["'" ++ X ++ "'" || X <- ["user2","user","user4"]], ",").
"'user2','user','user4'"
3> "(" ++ string:join(["'" ++ X ++ "'" || X <- ["user2","user","user4"]], ",") ++ ")".
"('user2','user','user4')"
```